# Multiple redirect uri's not working in slack

Tags: oauth-2.0, slack, slack-api

We are using oAuth using slack in our application.

**REQUIREMENT:**

What we want is to configure different redirect uri's for different domains ( like different redirect uri's for localhost, test and production mode)
and We have configured multiple redirect url's in app settings of slack and have also added redirect_uri in oAuth flow url as well.

**ERROR:**

But When user is authorized by slack and redirects back to the url oAuth flow url then we are getting "**bad_redirect_uri**" error in response. If we try by configuring single redirect uri in app settings, then it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to programming?

Comment: We have added slack button in our app for sign in/ sign up

Comment: Please add all details to your question by editing it. Also, share how this is related to programming

Comment: Without sharing the code you are using, it's impossible to provide help. Also, if you are solely configuring Slack or any existing oAuth application, this is off-topic here

Comment: We have just embedded a slack button ( button code from slack ) in our application to perform oAuth. And there's nothing like existing oAuth application, we have created our own application using angular in which we want to integrate oAuth using slack.